# Ubuntu 20.04,1 failing to install perl modules

Tags: drivers, perl

for example File::Slurp

````
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 06 Dec 2020 19:29:03 GMT
Running install for module 'File::Slurp'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CA/CAPOEIRAB/File-Slurp-9999.32.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring C/CA/CAPOEIRAB/File-Slurp-9999.32.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for File::Slurp
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  CAPOEIRAB/File-Slurp-9999.32.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for C/CA/CAPOEIRAB/File-Slurp-9999.32.tar.gz
Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.30/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2225.
  CAPOEIRAB/File-Slurp-9999.32.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
  No such file or directory
Failed during this command:
 CAPOEIRAB/File-Slurp-9999.32.tar.gz          : make NO```
````

Comment: Do you have `make` installed?

Comment: good question - "sudo apt-get install build-essential" -
its working!

Answer (score 2):

The cpan tool uses `make` to install Perl modules. You need to install `make` first.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

to install it.

Comment: thanks for saving my day <3